# why I am getting 404 error when creating a stripe checkout payment?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, axios, stripe-payments, http-status-code-404

I am creating a react-app with firebase, I want to use stripe payment Gateway in my project but i cant use it as it give me an error. Whenever I am calling a post request through axios , i get this error **POST: http://localhost:4242/payments 404 not found** .
this is my stripe checkout,
`<StripeCheckout stripeKey="PUBLIC_KE" token={handleToken} billingAddress shippingAddress amount={getBasketTotal(basket)} ></StripeCheckout>`

```
    async function handleToken(token) {
    console.log(token);
    const totalAmount = getBasketTotal(basket);
    const cart = { name: "All products", totalAmount };
    const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:4242/payments", {
    token,
    cart,
    });
    let { status } = response.data;
    console.log(response);
    if (status === "success") {
    navigate("/");
    toast.success("Your Order has been Placed Successfully!", {});
    } else {
    alert("Something went wrong!");
   navigate("/");
  //   toast.error("Something went wrong!", {});
    }
  }   

   app.post("/payments", (req, res) => {
   let error;
   let status;
   try {
   const { cart, token } = req.body;
  const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
  email: token.email,
   source: token.id,
    });
   const key = uuidv4();

  const charge = await stripe.charges.create(
   {
     amount: cart.totalAmount * 100,
     currency: "usd",
    customer: customer.id,
    receipt_email: token.email,
    description: "Product request Successfully recieved",
    shipping: {
      name: token.card.name,
      address: {
        line1: token.card.address_line1,
        line2: token.card.address_line2,
        city: token.card.address_city,
        country: token.card.address_country,
        postal: token.card.address_zip,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    idempotencyKey: key,
  }
);

 status = "success";
 } catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  status = "error";
  }
   res.json({ status });
   });

 app.listen(4242, () => console.log("Running on 4242"));
```

Any support would be helpful.

Comment: How are you running this? Are you sure you server is actually listening on port 4242 and responding to the /payments route? Can you hit that manually with curl/postman?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

My example:

```
const STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY
```

in React .env should be with REACT_APP prefix

userREQUEST:

```
const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/";  // my api is on 5000 
     const TOKEN = // yourToken - this one goes to header for auth 
    export const publicRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
   });

export const userRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    header: { token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}` },
});
```

CART PAGE:

```
const Cart = () => {
   const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
   let navigate = useNavigate();
// STRIPE Payment
   let [stripeToken, setStripeToken] = useState("");
  let onToken = (token) => {
setStripeToken(token);
};

useEffect(() => {
const makeRequest = async () => {

  try {
    let res = await userRequest.post("/checkout/payment", {
      tokenId: stripeToken.id,
      amount: cart.total * 100,
    });
    navigate("/success", {
      replace: true,
      stripeData: res.data,
      products: cart,
    });
  } catch { }
};
stripeToken && makeRequest();
}, [stripeToken, cart.total, cart, navigate]);

 return (
<div> 
<some elements />
<some elements />
<some elements />

//BUTTON 
<StripeCheckout
          name="SHOP NAME"
          image="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows- 
8/512/Logos-Google-Code-icon.png"
          billingAddress
          shippingAddress
          currency="EUR" // usd is default , you can ignore this for usd 
          description={`total: ${cart.total}`}
          amount={cart.total * 100} // 100 = 1.00usd 
          token={onToken}
          stripeKey={STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY}
        >
          <Button>PAY?</Button>
        </StripeCheckout>
 <div>
 )
```

Success page:

```
const Success = () => {
const location = useLocation();
const data = location.stripeData; // **location.state.stripeData FAILS!**
const cart = location.cart;
const currentUser = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser);
const [orderId, setOrderId] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    const createOrder = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await userRequest.post("/orders", {
                userId: currentUser._id,
                products: cart.products.map((item) => ({
                    productId: item._id,
                    quantity: item._quantity,
                })),
                amount: cart.total,
                address: data.billing_details.address,
            });
            setOrderId(res.data._id);
        } catch { }
    };
    data && createOrder();
}, [cart, data, currentUser]);

return (
    <div
        style={{
            height: "100vh",
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
        }}
    >
        {orderId
            ? `Order has been created successfully. Your order number is 
 ${orderId}`
            : `Successfull. Your order is being prepared...`}
        <button style={{ padding: 10, marginTop: 20 }}>Go to 
  Homepage</button>
    </div>
);
};

export default Success
```